# de Rham cohomology of $x^3+y^3 +z^3+c \,xyz= 0$ find representatives

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

The equation $x^3+y^3 +z^3+c\, xyz= 0$ defines a non-singular elliptic curve $X$ in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ projective space.

In fact, how do we prove it has genus 1 both as an algebraic curve and as a Riemann surface?

Since $H^1(X,\mathbb{C})\simeq \mathbb{C}^2$ what are the explicit representatives of the de Rham cohomology? There should be two of them.

Comment: Knowing it has genus 1 is not difficult; the degree-genus formula tells you that a (smooth) plane cubic has genus $(3-1)(3-2)/2 = 1$.

Comment: @jhf The proof of the degree-genus formula usesa small amount of **sheaf cohomology** via the [adjunction formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_formula) $K_D= (K_X+D) |_D$. So we do not get it for free! And I think also the [Riemann-Roch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Roch_theorem) theorem. Very advanced computations indeed. Yet at least we know $g=1$, like you said.

Comment: There are other proofs of the degree-genus formula that don't use sheaf cohomology.  For example, one can specialize to the singular case of the union of $d$ general lines, whose genus is easily calculated, and then perturb slightly to get a smooth degree $d$ curve.  Or one can use the Riemann-Hurwitz formula (by realizing the curve as a branched cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ via a general projection), etc.

Comment: Also, as for a basis for $H^1$, if you put your cubic curve into Weierstrass form $y^2 = f(x)$ (in affine coordinates), then you can just take $dx/ y$ and $x \, dx/y$ as a basis of holomorphic 1-forms.

Comment: @jhf right. so perhaps there is easy basis in homogenous coordinates as well such as $x \, dz$ and $x\, dy$.  maybe we can even get *explicit* sections of that line bundle here. these homology formulas succinctly encode what might be a page of algebra.

Comment: @jhf i had another question about the mapping class $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ on $H^1$ which I shall ask separately.

Comment: @JHF: Just the first form. The space of holomorphic 1-forms is 1-dimensional. (The second 1-form you wrote down has some poles, I believe.

Comment: @JHF This seems to only prove degree-genus for certain curves. It proves that any homology class which is the homology class of a smooth is represented by a curve satisfying genus degree, but I do not know why you think that shows it for all curves. (This was in reference to your first sketch, you can definitely use a result like Riemann Hurwitz to prove degree-genus.

Comment: can't you just pick $\omega_1 = (z dx - x dz) / (3y^2+cxz)$ and $\omega_2 = i \omega_1$ ?

Comment: @mercio can you?